# Captcha aggravation - chasing me away

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

If I use Tor browser with Disconnect Search engine it is not too bad but when I try to go to StackExchange I get tied up every time for about 5 minutes solving Captcha challenges. If I use my Firefox browser (without tor activated ) I get to StackExchange immediately with no challenges. I think it has something to do with cookies because when I turn my Firefox cookies option to off, I can not access my StackExchange account. I am still young at Tor and the learning curve is still steep so is there a way to have Tor know that I am a human and authorized to access my own account automatically or can someone direct me to somewhere that will help me understand how this works. I am currently using Firefox (without Tor activated) to access StackExchange because it is so much easier... and that should not be.

Comment: _"because when I turn my Firefox cookies option to off, I can not access my StackExchange account"_ - You mean you hit a Captcha page using non-Tor Firefox when you turn off cookies, or just that it doesn't remember who you are?

Comment: The problem when using Tor to access StackExchange, or any other Cloudflare site, is that Cloudflare knows the IP addresses of Tor's exit nodes, so can flag traffic coming from them.

Comment: When I turn cookies off Firefox Stack exchange simply will not come up - at all. No error message, nothing, no Captcha challenge or anything, like the screen has frozen except that without restarting, I can access my Firefox Options panel, turn the cookies back on and reload the StackExchange url pointing to my account and it loads immediately with no challenge at all.

Comment: Is Tor blacklisted on Cloudflare because the Captcha challenge rigamarole happens every time using the Tor browser.

Comment: @ron most likely because tor is kindof a proxy.

Comment: I now pretty well constantly use Firefox rather than Tor to access StachExchange because of the Captcha agro getting onto the site and I wonder if that defeats the who Tor concept?